# Fastest way to read files in C

Tags: c, io

I want to read files of the magnitude of GB's (like say 10 GB). What is the fastest way to read such a file in C. I am trying to do an implementation of `tail` but I think I/O can be a bottleneck. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: On what platform? With what operating system? With what else going on on the system? With what sort of storage architecture?

Comment: I/O is very operating system dependent, the fastest way varies from operating system to operating system. E.g. in Windows you would use the WinAPI to read the file as a memory mapped file therefore your question is a bit too vague atm.

Comment: I suspect you want to leave this to your standard C library. A proper standard library implementation is optimized enough so that it does not decreases performance.

Comment: @Zack If you decide to do a lot of backskipping, that is.

Comment: @Zack Of course I'm *not* suggesting the `FILE` API (I use it very rarely, indeed).

Comment: @H2CO3 What "standard library implementation" of file access in C is there, besides `FILE`?

Comment: @Zack `<fcntl.h>` - open, close, read, write.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what came first to my mind when I thought of the standard C library either, @H2CO3, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah, when someone says "standard C library" I think of what's in C99, which does *not* include `<fcntl.h>`.  Also, `open` and friends are as low-level as it gets on a POSIX system, you can't *not* use them, so the statement that you should "leave this to" them is bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I have yet to see a general purpose computer, where the physical IO is fast enough for files much bigger than any cache used, that the CPU-bound processing is the bottleneck. That said, I have not seen all general purpose computers in existance.

So you would have to balance CPU-cycle optimization against other factors, such as portability, maintainability and readability. I suspect most use cases, including the one given by you, would heavily point to simply using your runtime library functions, trusting, that the authors of those knew quite well, what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the low-level `read` system call to process the large file, not the more generic but also higher-overhead `fread`.  (It's okay to use `stdio.h` for the relatively small quantity of output you need to emit.)

You'll want to use `lseek` to skip most of the file and then scan backwards in chunks to find line boundaries.

I would avoid `mmap` for this application; it is liable to trigger unhelpful I/O heuristics in the kernel, and it adds a whole pile of portability headaches you don't need.

If that's not enough to get you going, post specific places where you get stuck as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there is no answer general to all environments.  The best you can do is benchmark many alternatives.

There are however a few things that will probably explain the results you get:

1. Overlapped computation and read operations:  Modern machines have Direct Memory Access (DMA) hardware and bus architectures that make it possible for data to be streaming from the disk into one or more buffers while you are processing a previously read buffers.  The idea is to run as many parallel streams as are needed to keep all device interfaces and busses operating at full capacity or else the CPU maxxed out with processing (and not useless copying as described below) or - in a perfect world - both.  For example, look at [Windows Overlapped IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Buffering:  The disk I/O hardware and drivers, the file system, the kernel/user space boundary, the language I/O API, and your own application code are all places where data can be buffered. In one instance I was able to identify 4 levels of buffering/cacheing in a PC when using a standard C library for text I/O.  This made it inevitable that every byte was copied at least 4 times.  The moral is that when you know for a fact that you're accessing a huge stream in sequential order, in raw form (e.g. no replacing \n with \r\n), and your application is all the machine should be doing when it runs, then those layers of buffering become mostly useless. The more you can eliminate by using lower-level interfaces, the faster you'll go.  The [Low Level Windows IO API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40bbyw78.aspx) at least eliminates all user space buffering and copying.
3. Disk channel performance and parallelism:  If the file is stored across more than one disk, for example with RAID, and the interfaces have separate DMA channels, the OS and/or your code can get the benefit of parallel hardware.  Similarly, in that you get what you pay for, not all disk interfaces are created equal.  This is a deep topic, but in general, servers are optimized for disk parallelism and high throughput.  Any application dealing with very large files is likely to run faster on server hardware than on an average PC, and there will be more opportunities to exploit asynchronous/overlapped IO.